# Qt QMenu QAction that is disabled but looks as enabled

Tags: qt, qaction

I would like to have an element of a popup menu that doesn't react to user inputs: click, hover, etc. but that doesn't look greyed out as when I disable it.

I have a `QMenu` to which I add a `QAction`

```
QMenu* menu// Further code creating the menu ...
QAction* titleAction = menu->addAction(QString::fromStdString("The Title"));
titleAction->setEnabled(false);
```

I have no experience with Qt. Maybe what I am doing is not the right approach to get what I want.

I tried setting the font

```
titleAction->font().setBold(true);
```

This is not enough to make it not be greyed out.
Maybe it is not even a QAction what I should be inserting in the menu but some other type of object. I need some initial guidance of what I should be trying to do, not so much the code but the philosophy of the QMenu for an entry that behaves like I said.

Comment: You mean it doesn't react *visually* (i.e. highlight and such)?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o Yes, and probably I should also say that it doesn't generate signals (not sure if that makes sense) when clicked.

Comment: Please check the accepted answer of the possible duplicate: using `QWidgetAction` as it suggests could solve your issue.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o Cool! Thank you.